# How can I get regular expression or comma when I use NSPredicate for array filtering in search bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex

My doubt is when i search a city name in search bar Ex Bangalore,KA it         returns empty array.So,now i need to get the array including Comma and when i type Bangalore,KA it should return the objects in array. but now when i type Bangalore it gives the objects in array but when i type Bangalore,KA it gives empty array. I need to get the comma and string after  using NSPredicate.Help me put Plz

```
  NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate
                                predicateWithFormat:@"restaurant_name CONTAINS[cd] %@",
                                searchText];

searchText = [searchText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@"searchText"];

    NSPredicate *resultPredicateCity = [NSPredicate
                                predicateWithFormat:@"city CONTAINS[cd] %@",
                                searchText];





  NSString *str = (NSString*)resultPredicate;

  NSString *strrr = (NSString*)resultPredicateCity;



//a_API

searchResults = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

[searchResults addObjectsFromArray:[newArr    filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate]];

[searchResults addObjectsFromArray:[newArr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicateCity]];



[_qSearchedDataHolderView setHidden:NO];

[_qSearchDataTableView reloadData];

if ([searchResults count]==0) {

    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:_locationSelector];

    [_locationSelector setHidden:NO];

    [_qSearchedDataHolderView setHidden:NO];

    [_qSearchDataTableView setHidden:YES];

}else{
    [_locationSelector setHidden:YES];

    [_qSearchedDataHolderView setHidden:NO];

    [_qSearchDataTableView setHidden:NO];

}
```

}

Expected Output Bangalore,KA

Receiving output Bangalore,

Comment: This is a peaceful site. Let's keep yelling to a minimum

Comment: What is an example the array data you are trying to match?

Comment: What is the structure of `newArr'? Is it an array of strings? Is it an NSObject with city and state as properties?

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I cannot understand what you are asking, you might want to try rewriting your question. However, in case it helps, consider your line:

```
searchText = [searchText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@"searchText"];
```

If the original value of `searchText` is:

```
Bangalore,KA
```

Then the resulting value will be:

```
BangaloresearchTextKA
```

Which I suspect is not what you intended. HTH

Comment: Actually Im dev a App for restaurants seat booking in map screen  when i go to search bar and type any restaurant name it gets me the required name using NSPredicate @"city CONTAINS[cd] %@" it fetches me the names according to array now my issue is when i type bangalore , ka it does not return anything . so, I need to get even the comma and text after the comma when i type in search bar using NSPredicate. So, can u tell me how to write the code

Comment: NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate
                                    predicateWithFormat:@"restaurant_name CONTAINS[cd] %@",
                                    searchText];
    
    searchText = [searchText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@""];
        
   NSPredicate *resultPredicateCity = [NSPredicate
                                    predicateWithFormat:@"city CONTAINS[cd] %@",
                                    searchText];

Comment: I use this Code when i type (Bangalore ,) the array objects are fetching it but when i type bangalore,KA it does not return me.

Comment: @zap Im trying to match with city array

Comment: @Vinod Vishwanath It is  an array of strings

Comment: @KiranKumar - Sorry but your question is no clearer. Guessing: you might find `componentsSeparatedByString:` useful.

Comment: No Im trying to filter the array using NSPredicate and i need to get the entire string including comma for EX: Bangalore , KA. so,how can i filter using NSPredicate including comma.